# postgis.control is not found on github actions

Tags: django, continuous-integration, github-actions

In my github actions yml, it can't find postgis.control. But, if `find /usr -name postgis.control` did, it can find postgis.control.

I don't know why test can't find postgis.control.. Any idea?

```
name: Django CI
on: push
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      max-parallel: 4
      matrix:
        python-version: [3.7]

    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:12
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
        env:
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
          POSTGRES_DB: ghostlabs_localhost
        options: --health-cmd pg_isready --health-interval 10s --health-timeout 5s --health-retries 5

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: psycopg2 prerequisites
      run: |
        sudo apt-get update && sudo apt remove -y postgis* postgresql* && sudo apt-get install -y libpq-dev gdal-bin postgresql-12 postgresql-12-postgis-3 postgresql-12-postgis-3-scripts postgresql-contrib-12
        echo "-----"
        find /usr -name postgis.control
    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements/localhost.txt
    - name: Run Tests
      run: |
        python manage.py migrate && python manage.py test
```

Log shows

```
-----
/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis.control
```

But, test has

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.11/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFile: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/12/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

The postgis extension is not distributed in the official postgresql docker image, you might want to install manually or use the following image for the service definition:

```
image: postgis/postgis:12
```

Also, as you are defining your job in VM, the port might not be available and the host will be localhost, so it is safer to define:

```
ports:
    - 5432/tcp
```

in the service definition, and later in the job definition set an environment variable that should be consumed in your settings file. If the variable is `DB_PORT`, you should add the following env to the steps using the database:

```
env:
  DB_HOST: localhost
  DB_PORT: ${{ job.services.postgres.ports[5432] }}
```

That should work!